# Angular ignoring special characters

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm trying to display a file name but when the name contains special characters it's completely ignored.

This is the code:

```
<p class="meta-description" [innerHTML]="{{ vm.previewing.filename + ' | ' + vm.previewing.emailSubject }}">
{ vm.previewing.filename }}

<span ng-if="vm.previewing.emailSubject"> | {{ vm.previewing.emailSubject }}</span>
```

Even adding [innerHTML] is not fixing the issue.

This is what shows up on the page if the file is named 'çx' for example:

```
<p class="meta-description ng-binding" [innerhtml]="x.pdf | ">
   x.pdf  
<!-- ngIf: vm.previewing.emailSubject -->
</p>
```

Comment: The question is tagged as AngularJS but looks like you are using Angular , the modern typescript version. Can you clarify the framework used ? This affects the answer.

Comment: For clarity can you also show an example of a subject line with a special character? Is it any special character or only certain ones?

Answer (score 0):

In case we are talking in AngularJS ,

Do you have the module angular-sanitize enabled ? If so use the ng-bind-html directive to parse special characters or markup to display. Also avoid mixing interpolation and property binding, choose only one to use.

```
<p class="meta-description" ng-bind-html="vm.previewing.filename + ' | ' + vm.previewing.emailSubject">


<span ng-if="vm.previewing.emailSubject" ng-bind-html="'|'+ vm.previewing.emailSubject"> </span>
```

A tip to make the code cleaner would be creating those string values on the controller side (like the concatenation of filename and email subject to the p element).

Please bear in mind that the bracket syntax "[]" is for Angular 2-11 property binding and not AngularJS.

Reference:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml